# How to plot relationship between each predictor and response in GLM with multiple predictor

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, structural-equation-modeling

I have a structural equation like this:

[image]

So I contruct two model which follow the formula of:
"B ~ A" and "C ~ A + B" 
The parameter for "B ~ A" will be β<sub>B0</sub>, β<sub>B1</sub>, σ<sub>B</sub>
The parameter for "C ~ A + B" will be β<sub>C0</sub>, β<sub>C1</sub>, β<sub>C2</sub>, σ<sub>C</sub>

On the plot of A(predictor) vs C(Response), if I want to plot the line contribute by A, it will be β<sub>C0</sub>+β<sub>C1</sub>*A+β<sub>C2</sub>*$\bar{B}$
My first question is, why do I need to add β<sub>C2</sub>$\bar{B}$? in the intercept?
My second question is, if I want to plot the line contribute by B, how Can I plot it?

Comment: Is **C** a binary outcome, or a count?  Otherwise, why are you using the `generalized-linear-model` tag?